# Creating a normalised Twitter database and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database-design

Hello I am creating a normalized Twitter DB for a project I am working on and wanted a bit of guidance on foreign keys.

I am curious about what the difference would be if for hashtags, symbols, user_mentions, urls and media, I made another field in each table called tweet_ID and the relationship changes to the primary key id in the tweet table to each tables tweet_id? The way I've modelled it means the tweets table has 5 extra fields for each tweet object.

Currently I have the schema designed as follows: 
[image: Schema 1]

Are there glaring issues with the way I have implemented the foreign keys in the model this way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for each tweet, you can have no more than one hashtag? That doesn't sound right to me.

For `tweets` and `hashtags` (and probably for the other four connected tables), I would create a "bridge" table, `tweet_hashtag`. This table would consist of:

- `tweet_id` (foreign key to the `tweets` table)
- `hashtag_id` (foreign key to the `hashtags`table)
- if appropriate, other columns that would apply only to the bridge table, if any (I can't think of any in this case, as I assume a tweet is created at  a single moment in time; if tweets could be edited, then a `created_on` date/time column could be appropriate)
- (Note: the combination of `tweet_id` and `hashtag_id` should be the primary key for this table, as you presumably should only note a given hashtag appears in a given tweet once. You can create a surrogate key (probably just an auto-increment integer or bigint value) if you really want to, or if you do need to be able to have multiple entries of the same hashtag for a single tweet for some reason)

This allows a given hashtag to be associated with many tweets, and a given tweet to have multiple (or no) hashtags.

As noted above, the same probably applies to the other four fields associated with the `tweets` table (`user_mentions`, `urls`, `media`, `symbols`).

Comment: @Adam - glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Can't judge a schema without seeing the queries that will be run.

Meanwhile, some gut observations...

- Hardly ever is it necessary to have 40 columns in a table.
- For scaling social media, counters (a la "Likes") should be in separate tables from the "static" data.
- Rethink each `VARCHAR(45)`; some look too big, some look too small.
- What `CHARACTER SET` will you be using?
- `LONGTEXT` and `BIGINT` are bulky and clumsy.  Are you expecting such large values?
- "link color" is a `LONGTEXT`??  I would expect `ENUM` or `TINYINT` (each only 1 byte) or `BINARY(3)` holding RGB.
- `statuses_count VARCHAR(45)` -- What's up?  Is it a single number; if so use a numeric type.  If it is a commalist of numbers, then you may be asking for trouble when extracting/updating it.
- What is `indices`??  The terminology conflicts with `INDEX`.
- What indexes exist on the tables?

One tweet can mention many users, correct?  Yet the columns don't support that.  The `mention` table needs `id_tweet`, not the other way around.